# Where do the electron and antineutrino come from in beta decay?

Tags: radioactivity

I was studying about nuclear reactions and similar stuff, but stumbled upon this doubt

In the process of beta decay, where a neutron transforms into a proton, a positron and an antineutrino, where do the electron and antineutrino come from ( do they already exist within the neutron or like? )

I do not believe that this is a duplicate of [In nuclear chemistry, how does a neutron split to form a proton and an electron?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/in-nuclear-chemistry-how-does-a-neutron-split-to-form-a-proton-and-an-electron)

Comment: Seems like a dupe to me though...

Comment: @Zhe, what i wanted to know wasnt what happens during the decay( any referance book gives that info) what i needed was the origin of the two particles, as cited by DavePhD

Comment: Though it looks like you got the answer you wanted, the question is probably more appropriate for the Physics SE. You are more likely to find a Physicist who knows this, since chemically we tend to take protons, neutrons, and electrons as being the smallest building blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A down quark of the neutron emits a virtual W- boson which becomes the electron and antineutrino pair.